# Use a controller as a service in a command

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf, symfony4

I'm trying to use Wkhtmltopdf from a Symfony Command.

I decided to use **KnpSnappyBundle**, so I created a controller used as a service.

**WkhtmltopdfController.php**

```
class WkhtmltopdfController extends Controller {

public function indexUrl()
{
    $snappy = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
    $filename = 'myFirstSnappyPDF';
    $url = 'http://ourcodeworld.com';


    return new Response(
        $snappy->getOutput($url),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'.pdf"'
        )
    );
}}
```

Then I import this service from my Command constructor like this.

**MyCommand**

```
class GenerateQuittance extends Command {

private $snappy;
private $container;

public function __construct(WkhtmltopdfController $knpSnappyPdf, ContainerInterface $container)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->snappy = $knpSnappyPdf;
    $this->container = $container;
}
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
 [...]
 $this->snappy->indexUrl();
}
```

But I get *[error] Error thrown while running command "app:myCommand". Message: "Call to a member function get() on null"*.

So how can I use my method from WkhtmltopdfController into a Command.

Thank you,

Comment: A controller isn't used for console commands. Please check the symfony docs. https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html

Comment: So how can I use Wkhtmltopdf from a command ? I was trying to create a Controller used as a Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injecting controller as a service is generally bad idea because they get special handling from Symfony. Consider refactoring your `WkhtmltopdfController::indexUrl()` method into separate service. You may also want to convert `$filename` variable into argument and convert method's return value into plain output instead of `Response`.

Please also notice that injecting `ContainerInterface` is also considered as a bad practice, you need to explicitly list services, you want to inject.

Your particular error most likely caused by a fact that `get()` method is provided by `ContainerTrait` that expects `ContainerInterface` to be available (by using `ContainerAwareTrait` in base container), but such injection may not happen in a case of console `Application`.

Comment: Thank you, so how must I do ? My objective is just to use Wkhtmltopdf in command line.

Comment: If you will review your code - you will see that the only line that you're actually using from controller is `$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutput($url)`. Hence you can inject `knp_snappy.pdf`service directly into your command and call `getOutput()` on it. A way to pass `$url` argument is up to you.